# View to list all nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

In my drupal installation I have created two type of nodes.

1. Free access (non - registered users)
2. Only member access (registered users)

I used a [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to set permissions.

Now I have created a list of these nodes using views, the problem is that when free user sees that list, they are **not shown** the list of nodes accessible only to registered users.

I want to be able to show all the list of nodes, regardless of who is seeing them, but when a non-registered clicks on node not be accessed by him, they will be taken to login page.

Please see [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460976/show-node-title-to-unregistered-users) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Premium](http://drupal.org/project/premium) module allows to show teasers to all users and the full body only to privileged users.

Comment: Will this allow me show a list of all nodes to even non-registered users ?
I have already defined control access on nodes, using another module. I'm unable to show all list to non-registered users.

Comment: I never used that module myself, but from the description on the module homepage it replaces other access controls, so you would have to disable the other module.

Comment: I didn't get time to check this module, hopefully someone who has done so will post it here.