# show node title to unregistered users

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm using [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to restrict certain nodes and node types for un-registered users.

But I would like to create a view where unregistered users can also see titles of those restricted nodes.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this personally, but I just saw it pop up in the drupal.org module feed a few days ago, and it should help: http://drupal.org/project/views_ignore_node_permissions

Comment: This module works. 
But for now set "Items to Display" to anything other than 0. It doesn't work with 0.

Answer (score 1):

ok if you just want to echo the node title in php (with in the node body ) enable php 
then :

```
<?php 
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) $nodeid = arg(1);
$node = node_load($nodeid);
print $node->title;

?>
```

> Blockquote

and you are done

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict access to some fields and not to others, you really should be using permissions per field. I assume all fields are built with CCK, so just enable permission for the content-type, but disable for all fields.

That way, only the title is visible. I don't think you can disable permissions for the standard body field, but I always use a CCK text-area for that anyway, it's alot easier also for css since the standard body field isn't wrapped in default node printing.

Comment: no, this is not possible, because there are 6 roles for the same content type and each node has been assigned access rules using the module above for the same content type.
I just want to show anonymous user the titles of restricted nodes as teaser.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple module for this, which does the following:

- query the node titles you want to show (called by hook_menu)
- theme the result (hook_theme)
- display the result (hook_block)

in the *hook_perm* you can create a new permission who you would like to show the node titles, if it is for everybody, just use 'access content'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ignore_node_permissions/issues/1122786#comment-4690058):

> In the views "Query options"-settings it's possible to set "Disable SQL rewriting" ("Disabling SQL rewriting will disable node_access checks as well as other modules that implement hook_query_alter().") which afaik makes this module unneeded with the latest views version.